# Javalin/Kotlin OpenAPI error: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined

Tags: kotlin, build.gradle, swagger-ui, openapi, javalin

Is there anything I am missing?
Had the code that worked locally, when deployed I get

> ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined

After I cleared my browsing data I get the same error locally as well. Below are the configurations:

**build.gradle**

```
    implementation("io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core:2.0.9")
    implementation("org.webjars:swagger-ui:3.24.3")
    implementation("io.github.classgraph:classgraph:4.8.34")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.10.1")
```

**App.kt**

```java
fun main() {
    val app = Javalin.create { config ->
        config.enableCorsForAllOrigins()
        config.showJavalinBanner = false
        config.enableWebjars()
        config.registerPlugin(getConfiguredOpenApiPlugin())
    }
    configureApp(app, Config)
    app.start(7000)
}

fun getConfiguredOpenApiPlugin() = OpenApiPlugin(
    OpenApiOptions(
        Info().apply {
            version("1.0")
            description("Polaris API")
        }
    ).apply {
        activateAnnotationScanningFor("search")
        path("/swagger-docs")
        swagger(SwaggerOptions("/swagger").title("Polaris Swagger Documentation"))
    }
)
```

**Endpoint.kt** annotations

```java
    @OpenApi(
        description = "Description",
        path = "/get/something",
        method = HttpMethod.GET
    )
    override fun handleEndpoint(ctx: Context) {
       // Code here
    }
```

For reference, Javalin documentation: https://javalin.io/plugins/openapi

Also, I'll attach all errors from the browser console. It's looking for `3.22.2` files when I set the `3.24.3` swagger-ui version in the build.gradle.

```
The script from “http://localhost:7000/webjars/swagger-ui/3.22.2/swagger-ui-bundle.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/plain”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.

The script from “http://localhost:7000/webjars/swagger-ui/3.22.2/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/plain”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.

Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:7000/webjars/swagger-ui/3.22.2/swagger-ui-bundle.js”.
The script from “http://localhost:7000/webjars/swagger-ui/3.22.2/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/plain”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.

Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:7000/webjars/swagger-ui/3.22.2/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js”.

ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined
```

Comment: I did run a gradle clean, also removed .gradle folder altogether, tried different browsers, different ports, different paths.
I don't have anything configured for version `3.22.2` either.

Comment: Hi. Did you solve this? I am getting the same MIME type error with other JS files. Do you know why this happened?